# Add core data to existing tabbed application project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, appdelegate

I started a project without selecting core data. Now I would like to save and retrieve from core data and am going about implementing it in my project. What is the right way of adding core data to an existing project in Swift 3, Xcode 8.2? All the tutorials I have found online have core data selected already and other methods seem out of date.

So far I have done: 
1. Added a core data model file called useCoreData.
2. Added 'import CoreData' in AppDelegate 
3. Started a new single application project on Xcode and copied the following code from that project and added into the end of AppDelegate of my project

```
             // MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    /*
     The persistent container for the application. This implementation
     creates and returns a container, having loaded the store for the
     application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate
     error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
     */
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MY_PROJECT_NAME")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.

            /*
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The parent directory does not exist, cannot be created, or disallows writing.
             * The persistent store is not accessible, due to permissions or data protection when the device is locked.
             * The device is out of space.
             * The store could not be migrated to the current model version.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.
             */
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // fatalError() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

4. Added self.saveContext() into Applicationwillterminate in AppDelegate.

Is there anything else that needs to be done? Because I see in previous tutorials of adding Core Data needs to have the following as well but it comes up with a bunch of errors when I add it but not sure if it needs to be adapted or this extra section doesn't need to be added with Swift 3?

```
    // MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "y.Simple_Grade" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
    }()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("my_app", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
    }()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("my_app.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
    }()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
    }()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just start a new project and see what the template adds? But really, before using Core Data, I recommend doing a course or a tutorial.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. But there is inconsistency with the tutorials on CoreData talk about the NSURL, NSFileManager etc and I am not sure if that is something I should be adding on top of my template or this is not appropriate anymore for latest version of xcode/swift and tutorials are out of date?

Comment: The template has been updated with new iOS 10 class, `NSPersistentContainer`, which simplifies setup, but is only available for iOS 10 and above.

Comment: Ok great! that means I don't have to add anything after coping the template from another project. Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Yes. Just note that this only gets you through initial setup. After that, you still have to learn to use Core Data.